# TransmitFile file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, export-to-excel

I am generating an Excel file on the server and then immediately download it to the user. This is my code on the button click:

```
 var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
 excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
 Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

 string fileTemporary = "C:\\Users\\........\\Desktop\\my folder\\";
 fileTemporary = fileTemporary  + nameOfDocument+".xlsx";
 workSheet.SaveAs(fileTemporary);

 HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileTemporary);
```

I got the error that the file is being used by another process, even though I have JUST created the file. I added everyone as a user to that folder and am running vs as an administrator.

**Update:** After people told me to close the sheet, i tried this:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);
```

before calling the Transmitfile and i kept having the problem

**Update 2:** I also tried this:

```
excelApp.Quit();
```

**Update 3:** I tried this:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workSheet);
excelApp.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);

HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileTemporary);
```

the thing is that now i don't get any exception, but nothing is being downloaded

Comment: Did you created it through Interop? If yes, you'll need to close it in the Excel application.

Comment: Rubens is correct, your file needs to be closed before you can transmit it

Comment: @RubensFarias yes i did, how can i close it please?

Comment: @RubensFarias i updated my quesiton,

Comment: @SimonPrice i update my question please help

Comment: Try to close the workbook, or quit the Excel application. BTW, if you should output a simple HTML table to export tabular data, or go with openxml for more elaborated workbooks. You'll regret using Interop in a server side application real quick.

Comment: @RubensFarias i have just update my quesiton again, i don't get exception with the last code, but nothing is being downloaded, it seems that last line is not working, could you check please

Comment: @RubensFarias no i am exporting a big big data.

Comment: I'm out of bullets. If it's only data, you should really take a look into HTML tables with the appropriate content type. G'luck!

Comment: @RubensFarias i wonder why you are trying to force me to do something i don't want to. i have a problem in a specific thing and your soultion now is to re engineer the whole thing? have you ever worked with a team ? really?

Comment: I don't want to force your to do anything, buddy, please yourself. ;-) Have a nice day!

Comment: @RubensFarias thanks u too

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli rubens was only trying to give you the benefit of his experience.  Can you be more detailed about what it is you are trying to do? Are you reading the file and then outputting it to a webpage, or something else? his suggestion of openXML may be the better way, either that or my preference which is closedXML which is extremely easy to deal with too.

Comment: @SimonPrice i want to download the file to the cliient, that is it. the file is in the fileTemporary path (path + name)

Comment: check out and try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this what worked to me

```
GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workSheet);
            excelApp.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is your code, plus a close and a quit

```
 var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
 excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
 Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

 String fileTemporary = "C:\\Users\\........\\Desktop\\my folder\\";
 fileTemporary = fileTemporary  + nameOfDocument+".xlsx";
 workSheet.SaveAs(fileTemporary);

workSheet.Close(0); 
excelApp.Quit();

HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileTemporary);
```

Comment: the same exception< i wrote my answer

Answer (score 0):

If downloading file is your case now and this is a web, you may want to consider using the URL's path instead of the actual path and send it back to through Response.Redirect OR Response.AppendHeader

```
     string fileTemporary = "~/TempFiles/";
     string actualLoc = fileTemporary.Replace("~",HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(""));
     if(!Directory.Exists(actualLoc)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(actualLoc); }
     string newActualLoc = actualLoc + nameOfDocument + ".xlsx";
     string linkLoc = fileTemporary + nameOfDocument + ".xlsx";

     workSheet.SaveAs(newActualLoc);

     GC.Collect();
     GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workSheet);
     excelApp.Quit();
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

plus with redirect

```
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(linkLoc);
```

or append header

```
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + linkLoc);
```